# Using toupper for first character in the vector string

Tags: c++

How to use `toupper()` to convert the first letter to uppercase of each element inside a vector of strings?

This is what I've tried...

```cpp
string word;
vector<string> text;
while(cin >> word){
    text.push_back(word);
}

for(decltype(text.size()) i = 0; i != text.size()) {
    text[0] = toupper(text);
}
```

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve, I suggest you do add the current output and expected Output

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
for(auto& s : text)
    if (!s.empty()) s[0] = std::toupper(s[0]);
```

Or more fancy:

```cpp
std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin}, {},
              std::back_inserter(text),
              [](auto s) {
                  if (!s.empty()) s[0] = std::toupper(s[0]);
                  return s;
              });
```

Comment: Technically you need `std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[0]))`

Comment: if you are taking about none ASCII characters then topic is much more complex then simple `static_cast<unsigned char>(s[0])`.

Comment: thanks! can you explain why didn'y my version work? Because it did using normal strings but when using on vector compiler says: "no matching function for call to 'toupper'

Comment: since `std::toupper` accepts values of type of `int` (or `char` which can be silently converted to `int`), and your code was feeding there a value of `std::vector<std::string>` type. Basically your choice of symbols names is misleading.

Comment: @MarekR The check for `s.empty()` is not needed since `text` will never hold blank strings due to the use of `operator>>` when populating `text`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this,

```cpp
string word;
vector<string> text;
while(cin >> word){
    word[0] = static_cast<char>(toupper(static_cast<int>(word[0])));;
    text.push_back(word);
}
```

Now you don't have to iterate through the word list to change the first letter of every entry to upper.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

Your 2nd loop runs endlessly, you need to add `++i` to the end of the loop to actually iterate each string in the vector and terminate the loop when the end of the vector is reached:

```cpp
for(decltype(text.size()) i = 0; i != text.size(); ++i)
```

On a side note, you can replace `decltype(text.size())` with `vector<string>::size_type` instead, or `decltype(text)::size_type`.

A [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) would avoid both issues:

```cpp
for(string &str : text)
```

Regarding your actual error, this line does not compile:

```cpp
text[0] = toupper(text);
```

Because `toupper()` takes a single character as input, but you are passing it the vector itself, rather than a single character from a single string in the vector.  You would have needed to do this instead:

```cpp
text[i][0] = toupper(text[i][0]);
```

However, you actually need to convert characters to `unsigned char` when passing them to `toupper()`, eg (I'm separating each step so you can see it more clearly):

```cpp
string &str = text[i];
char ch = str[0];
unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(ch);
uc = toupper(uc);
ch = static_cast<char>(uc);
str[0] = ch;
text[i] = str;
```

Which, obviously, can also be written as a string expression, if you want:

```cpp
text[i][0] = static_cast<char>(
  toupper(
    static_cast<unsigned char>(
      text[i][0]
    )
  )
);
```

The reason why the cast is needed is explained on [this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper):

> Parameters
>
> ch - character to be converted. **If the value of ch is not representable as `unsigned char` and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ...
>
> Like all other functions from `<cctype>`, the behavior of std::toupper is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as `unsigned char` nor equal to EOF. To use these functions safely with plain `char`s (or `signed char`s), the argument should first be converted to `unsigned char`